# KDM Theme in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, 14.04, kdm

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 14.04, and when I went to reconfigure KDM (because I'm not a fan of the current theme), I realized that there was no way to add more themes, and there were only two there. How can I install themes for KDM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Login Screen**

From the Kubuntu 12.10 the default login manager has been the LightDM: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/12.10-release.  KDE System settings > Login Screen(LightDM)

[image]

**KDM**

The KDE login manager can be installed to the Kubuntu. The package is kdm.

> :~$ apt-cache show kdm
>
> Package: kdm
>
> Priority: optional
>
> Section: universe/kde
>
> ...
>
> Description: KDE Display Manager for X11
>
> KDM manages
>   a collection of X servers running on local or remote machines.  It
>   allows users to easily log into their preferred desktop environment,
>   connect  to a remote XDMCP server, or shut down the system.  .  KDM
>   supports custom themes and can display a list of users with icons. 
>   Additional user icons can be found in the 'kdepasswd' package.  . 
>   This package is part of the KDE base workspace module.
>
> Homepage: http://www.kde.org/

After the installation the KDM themes can be installed from the KDE System settings > Login Screen - Theme tab - 'Get New Themes' or 'Install new theme'.

[image]

The KDM control module can be started with the command:

```
kdesudo kcmshell4 kdm


:~$ kcmshell4 --help
Usage: kcmshell4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] module 

A tool to start single KDE control modules

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --list                    List all possible modules

Arguments:
  module                    Configuration module to open
  --lang <language>         Specify a particular language
  --silent                  Do not display main window
  --args <arguments>        Arguments for the module
```

This is a workaround for the KDE bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255453

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that Kubuntu shipped with lightDM instead of KDM. Just a heads up to anyone who needs to install themes for KDM, you need to be root to install any themes (this has been a bug for a while, it seems). To do this, open Konsole and type `sudo systemsettings`. Be sure to keep Konsole running, as pressing the close button on the window does not kill the process.