# Ubuntu booting with KDE problem

Tags: 12.04, boot, gnome, 14.04, kde

I have deleted KDE from my `ubuntu 14.04`. But now when I restart the system its trying to bring-up the display with KDE and as there is no KDE available I am getting a black screen.

Is there any way to boot with default GNOME or in recovery mode.? I am unable to see anything, so can't change anything graphically. I am able to login in TTY1.

I have used the below command to install and uninstall the KDE desktop:

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Uninstall:

```
sudo aptitude remove kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: you must use `sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop` to remove the configuration files

Comment: alternatively, `sudo aptitude purge kubuntu-desktop` if you want to use aptitude

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like when you installed KDE you let it switch your default Desktop Manager from LightDM to KDM. KDM would have been removed when you uninstalled KDE, because of this you get a black screen at bootup. You will need to switch back to LightDM as your default Desktop Manager.

## Steps:

1. In terminal type "`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`".
2. In terminal type "`sudo reboot`".

## Notes:

- If you don't have LightDM installed for some reason then you can install it by typing in terminal `"sudo apt-get install lightdm"`.

---

EDIT #1:

In response to your edit regarding how you installed/removed KDE I believe the problem was that you used aptitude when removing instead of apt-get remove. Aptitude removes packages using a list generated during the install but you didn't use aptitude during the install, apt doesn't use a pre-generated list. It's likely something you need got accidentally removed because of this. I would suggest installing lightdm & ubuntu-desktop again as this will re-install any missing dependencies. In terminal type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`.

Comment: Thanks. But still the problem is not solved. Is there any way I can boot the 14.04 in recovery mode or can everything to default mode??

Comment: No.. Its the same black screen when I am trying to start "sudo start lightdm".

Comment: @roy what command did you use to install kde, and what command did you use to remove it? Edit this into your posting.

Comment: @mchid Even if you install kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu it will install KDM...atleast when I type in apt-get I see it listed to be installed.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to go to the default mode of Ubuntu. I am new to Ubuntu, so tried the KDE desktop and then felt to go back to the default on, i guess that's Unity.But then encounter with the error.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452672/kdm-theme-in-kubuntu-14-04

Comment: @mchid That's Kubuntu, the OP is running Ubuntu. The result is different.

Comment: correct, that is why the configuration files from a previous kde installation running lightdm may conflict with his current setup

Comment: It is true that remove doesn't remove the config files, but aptitude and apt remove packages differently.

Comment: @mchid Just a heads up I'm going to remove some of my old comments as this is getting cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. tty1 **IS** a recovery environment.

First, try to start an xsession to see if the problem is related to X11. To do this, sign in on tty1 with your username and password, then type in the following command

```
startx
```

this should start an xsession on tty7 (CTRL + ALT + F7) and should automatically take you there if launch of the xsession is successfull. You can see the output of any errors on tty1 (CTRL + ALT + F1)

If you are talking about the "splash screen" (blue screen that says Kubuntu with the dots under that light up) it has nothing to do with KDE and is a separate screen saver like program called plymouth that only serves the purpose of looking cool.

To view a text output and to see errors that take place during this process press F2 when the splash screen is displayed.

Starting with 14.04, Kubuntu now uses lightdm and may still be configured to use the kde defaults. To get around this issue, install gdm

```
 sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and you should be prompted to select lightdm or gdm, choose gdm as the default.

if gdm is already installed, use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and select gdm as the default.

After installation, use the command

```
sudo service gdm start
```

from tty1 to start the login screen.

Also, BTW, to start lightdm, you can use the following command

```
sudo service lightdm
```

If there are any errors, they will be displayed on tty1 (CTRL + ALT + F1).